# How are void methods different, or why I can't call a void method, when an int method works fine?

Tags: c++, methods, global-variables

Why is it ok to call an `int` method outside `main` but calling a `void` method throws an error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int foo();
        void bar();
};

int A::foo() {
    cout << "called foo()" << endl;
    return 123;
};

void A::bar() {
    cout << "called bar()" << endl;
};


A* a = new A();
int a_val = a->foo();
a->bar();                              // error: unknown type name 'a'


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    a->bar();
  cout << a_val << endl ;
}
```

The error is:

```
main.cpp:24:1: error: unknown type name 'a'
a->bar();  // error: unknown type name 'a'
^
main.cpp:24:2: error: cannot use arrow operator on a type
a->bar();  // error: unknown type name 'a'
 ^
```

2 errors generated.

When that line is commented out, the output is:

```
called foo()
called bar()
123
```

Comment: Because the statement `a->bar();` is not an initialization. It belongs in `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int` method also doesn't work if you don't assign it

```
a->foo(); //error: unknown type name 'a'
```

That's because you can't call functions in global scope, it doesn't make any sense (i.e. are they executed multiple times for each `#include`?).

Assigning the return value to a variable make sense, because then you are defining a global variable, which has the value of the function you are calling. That's ok, even though it can cause problems, see multiple definitions.

**TL;DR** You can only define, declare and initialize variables/functions/structs/classes in global scope, not anything else.

Comment: We can initialize stuff in the global scope as well. We can also call functions that return values that are used to initialize more stuff. It seems only logical to think that we can initialize stuff from within a function. And we actually can initialize stuff from within a function (!) as long as that function also initializes *something* (i.e. its return value is used to initialize something). Well ok, I can live with that.